# How to efficiently prepend a vector to a vector

Tags: c++11, stdvector

I have 2 vectors like so:

```
std::vector<unsigned char> v1;
std::vector<unsigned char> v2;
```

Each of them has some data of course.

I know that following is the way if I want to append v2 to v1.
    v1.insert(v1.end(), v2.begin(), v2.end());

**Question:**
How can I prepend v1 to v2 instead?
`v2.insert(v2.begin(), v1.begin(), v1.end())` doesn't seem to work here?

I know that I might get suggestions of using `std::deque` instead but the problem is that `v2` is coming as a `std::vector` out of a function in a legacy piece of code which I cannot change. And it contains a huge amount of data which I do not want copy over to `v2` by appending. So, I simply want to prepend `v1` to `v2` because `v1` is extremely small compared to `v2`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This does work very well:

```
std::vector<int> a{ 1,2,3,4 };
std::vector<int> b{ 5, 6, 7 };
a.insert(a.begin(), b.begin(), b.end());
// a is  {5, 6, 7, 1, 2, 3, 4}
```

What problem did you face?

Comment: It works well. I was stupidly doing an unrelated mistake and got confused.

Comment: This works nicely on clang but gets into trouble on arm built with gnu. vector `a` I have quite big. Should there be some resizing of  `a` I should/might have to do?